# Running a Python Application 24x7 - Design question

Tags: python, machine-learning, server, stock

I have a python functionality in Jupyter notebook/ Google Colab which checks current stock prices and other computations. I'm planning to set up some alerts based on some triggers. So for being able to be running throughout the business day, how and where do I run the code?

i. How do I run the python code 24x7? Do I need to have a designated server that runs 24/7?
ii. Should I be changing my code to python scripts rather than using notebooks?
iii. Is there a good reference for the python project structure?
iv. Any suggestions on python libraries for setting up email/sms/Whatsapp alerts?
v. I'm planning to add ML features in the future. Should I be using cloud functions vs local GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.**
You can run a python script with the compiler of your choice such as Visual Studio or PyCharm. However, this drains your CPU and may not be the best option for running at all times. Personally, I use to edit my files with Vim and use Git Bash to the scripts. I have had scripts running for a few hours while using my computer with no problems.

**II.**
You can use a standard text editor or a python compiler. It's up to you whether
you want to track your errors or not.

**III.**
I don't want my answer to get flagged for advertising so I am just going to say a simple search for "Best Python Books" will give a few results that are great. But, for reference, you can refer to the official python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/

**IV.**
A good library for sending SMS messages/Whatsapp messages is Twilio. You can just input the sender phone number and the receiver number and that is basically it for sending a text. Here is some more info: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python.

For email, you can use a standard email system such as SMTP. Here is some more info on that: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

**V.**
It depends on what your end goal is for this application. If you plan on just showing it off to your friends and family, a local GPU should be fine. But if you plan to release it to the public, using a cloud server is one of the best options.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

One design solution would be to use a cloud provider like google cloud platform or amazon web services to schedule the execution of a python script. The involved gcp services would be Pub/Sub, Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Functions, Storage and Cloud Source Repositories.

- Pub/Sub := an asynchronous messaging service
- Cloud Scheduler := a cronjob scheduler
- Cloud Functions := Functions-as-a-Service, deploys automatically a Compute Engine and Storage to execute the python script and deletes the Compute Engine and Storage afterwards.
- Cloud Repository := private Git repository

1. You create a topic/channel with Pub/Sub.
2. You set up a cronjob via Cloud Scheduler to send a message periodically to the previously created pub/sub topic.
3. You connect your GitHub repository which consists the python script with the Cloud Source Repository (Cloud Source Repository will from now on sync automatically with your GitHub Repository)
4. You create a function with Cloud Functions and use your Cloud Source Repository as the source code for the function. As a trigger for this function you set any message which is send to the previously created Pub/Sub topic.
5. The python script could include the yfinance library to request the stock data, the google cloud libraries to handle the data storage via GCP Storage and then you could potentially extend it with other google cloud libraries to include ML services.